# Jundefined method `booking_items' for #<BookingItemSerializer:0x0000558b758121c0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, active-model-serializers

I was trying to create a Booking Space API.  I am getting this error. Can someone help me with this. Is  there any other method to call booking_items_attribute. I was building an space booking API

```
 NoMethodError in Api::V1::BookingsController#create
undefined method `booking_items' for #<BookingItemSerializer:0x0000558b758121c0>
Extracted source (around line #12):
10
11
12
13
14


  def booked
    self.booking_items.sum(:count)
  end
end
```

Booking Item serializer

```
class BookingItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes  :entity_type, :count,  :booked


  belongs_to :booking,  serializer: BookingItemSerializer
  belongs_to :meeting_rooms, serializer: MeetingRoomSerializer
  belongs_to :private_offices, serializer: PrivateOfficeSerializer
  belongs_to :desks, serializer: DeskSerializer
  belongs_to :operating_hours, serializer: OperatingHourSerializer

  def booked
    self.booking_items.sum(:count)
  end
end
```

Booking Controller

```
class Api::V1::BookingsController < ApiController
  before_action :fetch_space, only: [:show]

  def index
    bookings = Booking.all
    render_collection(bookings, { name: 'bookings' }, each_serializer: BookingItemSerializer )
  end

  def create
    if booking = current_user.bookings.create(booking_params)
      render_object(booking, { name: 'booking' }, { serializer: BookingSerializer })
    else
      render_error(booking.errors.full_messages)
    end
  end

  private


  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:space_id,
      booking_items_attributes: [:id, :entity_type, :entity_id, :count],
      booking_dates_attributes: [:id, :from_date, :to_date, :from_time, :to_time])
    end
  end
```

Booking Serializer

```
class BookingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user_id, :space_id, :status
  has_many :booking_items, serializer: BookingItemSerializer

end
```

Requested json

```
{
   "booking": {
       "space_id": 17,
       "booking_items_attributes": [
           {
               "entity_type": "PrivateOffice",
               "entity_id": 20,
               "count": 1
           },
            {
               "entity_type": "Desk",
               "entity_id": 20,
               "count": 1
           },
            {
               "entity_type": "PrivateOffice",
               "entity_id": 20,
               "count": 1
           }
       ],
        "booking_dates_attributes": [
           {
               "from_date": "2020-03-18",
               "to_date": "2020-03-18",
               "from_time": "2020-03-18 10:00:00 ",
               "to_time": "2020-03-18 14:00:00 "
           }]
   }
}
```

This is what the output json should look like

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "booking": {
            "id": null,
            "user_id": 31,
            "space_id": 17,
            "status": null,
            "booking_items": [
                {
                    "entity_type": "PrivateOffice",
                    "count": 1,
                    "booked" :1
                },
                {
                    "entity_type": "Desk",
                    "count": 1
                    "booked" :1
                },
                {
                    "entity_type": "PrivateOffice",
                    "count": 1
                    "booked" :1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably be `object.booking_items.sum(:count)` but this will still give a N+1 query issue as each item serialized will create a query.

Comment: @max now am getting this error       undefined method `booking_items' for #<BookingItem:0x0000558b75c243d0> Did you mean? booking_id booking_id= booking_id? booking_id_was

Comment: What is this code even supposed to do? It just makes less sense the more I look at it. Your BookingItemSerializer is called for every item serialized so if you want to add a tally to the gereral response this is not the way. `.sum(:count)` is also strange, even if this did work it would SUM the column called `count` not provide a count of the association. You do that by calling `.size`.

Comment: I will attach the json request. I was trying to make a space booking api and this booked method should show number of bookings.

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual desired output instead?

Comment: output json attached @max

Comment: Thanks - but still the more I dig the less sense it makes. From what I can see you have some sort of one to many association between Booking and booking_items yet in the controller you have a bunch of Booking records but you're rendering them with BookingItemSerializer. Is this some sort of weird self referential setup? Is also extremely unclear what all these counts are actually counts of. Have you really thought though the modeling at all before you got to this stage?

Comment: count in the sense no:of space the user want like whether he wants @ desks or 3 private offices like that

Comment: So you actually have a column named count? I can think of many reasons why that's a really bad idea. Use `quantity` or any other synonym.

Comment: I still don't get why you think you should be doing `each_serializer: BookingItemSerializer` instead of `each_serializer: BookingSerializer` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BookingItemSerializer`,

replace your `booked` method with

```
def booked
    self.booking.booking_items.sum(:count)
end
```